# Script for detecting height and changing padding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a chunk of text. There is a title which is in the chunk of text. It can either be 25 or 50 pixels high depending if it's 1 or 2 lines. The title is a p tag inside of a div with the css aspect of height: auto;. I am using a script to detect the height of the div. By default the div is 25 high with 1 line. If so nothing changes. If it is 50 pixels high, it should include style tags with some still inside changing the padding of a different dive moving the text around. I currently have this script running (it doesn't work which is why I am requesting help):

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
 if ($('.rtitle').height() == 50) {
 document.write("<style>
    div#raffleinfo {
     height: 127px;
     padding-top: 173px;
    }</style>)";
 }
});
</script>
```

```css
div#raffledisplay {
 height: 300px;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
}

div#raffleinfo {
 float: left;
 width: 480px;
 height: 102px;
 padding-top: 198px;
 background-color: red;
}

div#rtitle {
 height: auto;
}

p.rtitle {
 font-size: 35;
 line-height: 25px;
}

p.rinfo {
 font-size: 25;
 line-height: 25px;
}

#progressBar {
 width: 478px;
 height: 25px;
 border: 1px solid #111;
 background-color: #292929;
}
```

```html
<div id="raffledisplay">
 <div id="raffleinfo">
  <div id="rtitle"><p class="rtitle">$weapon | $skin $stattrack</p></div>
  <p class="rinfo">Quality: $quality</p>
  <p class="rinfo">Price: $price</p>
  <div id="progressBar" class="pbar"><div></div></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I am not sure why it's displaying all weird if you run the code, but on my website it looks fine...

Comment: Probably because some of those variables are PHP ones and that is not being run here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // console.log($('.rtitle').height());
  if ($('.rtitle').height() == 50) {
    $("div#raffleinfo").addClass('larger');
  }
});
```

```css
div#raffledisplay {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
div#raffleinfo {
  float: left;
  width: 480px;
  height: 102px;
  padding-top: 198px;
  background-color: red;
}
div#raffleinfo.larger {
  height: 127px;
  padding-top: 173px;
}
div#rtitle {
  height: auto;
}
p.rtitle {
  font-size: 35;
  line-height: 25px;
}
p.rinfo {
  font-size: 25;
  line-height: 25px;
  //background-color: green;
}
#progressBar {
  width: 478px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #111;
  background-color: #292929;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="raffledisplay">
  <div id="raffleinfo">

    <div id="rtitle">
      <p class="rtitle">$weapon $skin $stattrack xxxxxxxx xx xxx xx  xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxx </p>
    </div>

    <p class="rinfo">Quality: $quality</p>
    <p class="rinfo">Price: $price</p>

    <div id="progressBar" class="pbar">
      <div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Honestly Simon is right, addClass is probably the way to go, then you can do an else and use removeClass to take it back off.

Comment: I have added the extra css class and inserted that code snippet into my php doc but it doesn't seem to work.

EDIT: Just noticed that the code is checking if the class rtitle is 50px not the id. Does that make a difference since the id has the height auto. I tried changing it but didn't work. Any fix?

Comment: I forgot to add quotes here `.addClass('larger');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, create a custom class with your features, and add it to your element whenever required.

The reason why your code is not working is because the DOM already loads and reads CSS code. So the moment you are inserting it the way you do, it doesn't do anything because it finished doing that. You can only add elements, but not style to already rendered elements. To add style to already rendered elements, use [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) as I've did below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('.rtitle').height() == 50) {
    $('#raffleinfo').addClass('customclass');
  }
});
```

```css
div#raffledisplay {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
div#raffleinfo {
  float: left;
  width: 480px;
  height: 102px;
  padding-top: 198px;
  background-color: red;
}
div#rtitle {
  height: auto;
}
p.rtitle {
  font-size: 35;
  line-height: 25px;
}
p.rinfo {
  font-size: 25;
  line-height: 25px;
}
#progressBar {
  width: 478px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #111;
  background-color: #292929;
}
.customclass {
  height: 127px;
  padding-top: 173px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="raffledisplay">
  <div id="raffleinfo">
    <div id="rtitle">
      <p class="rtitle">$weapon | $skin $stattrack</p>
    </div>
    <p class="rinfo">Quality: $quality</p>
    <p class="rinfo">Price: $price</p>
    <div id="progressBar" class="pbar">
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```